# Nodetool command having issue when using it on remote host in the same cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, thrift, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

if we run nodetool for any other host from a node in the same cluster, we are getting an error. Though it works fine for local host.

```
nodetool -h 10.241.17.81 status 
nodetool: Failed to connect to '10.241.17.81:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.
```

Here, `10.241.17.81` is the remote host in the same cluster .

It doesn't work even after adding `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.241.17.81"` in cassandra-env.sh and restarting the node.

Is there something related to broadcast_rpc_address?

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_rpc_address: 10.241.17.81
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the following in cassandra-env.sh:

```
if [ "x$LOCAL_JMX" = "x" ]; then
    LOCAL_JMX=yes
```

to

```
if [ "x$LOCAL_JMX" = "x" ]; then
    LOCAL_JMX=no
```

and

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true"
```

to

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

And restart the node.

Also, before making these changes, be sure to check your hosts by using the command:

```
netstat -antp.
```

Comment: I believe the confusion stems from this bizarre BASH gibberish "x$LOCAL_JMX" = "x" which as I recall says something like "the variable has not been initialized". Pretty sure that is it so you can code LOCAL_JMX=no right in cassandra-env.sh as I did and it corrects the issue without side effects or just change the code as shown above.